# HDMI Source output to HDMI splitter to 2x HDMI to VGA converter (active, not externally powered) to 2x Monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I need help with this setup of mine. The setup situation goes like below:

1. One HDMI source (android TV box) outputs to HDMI splitter (powered) which supports up to 4K.
2. HDMI splitter outputs to two 2x HDMI to VGA converter through a 3m and 6m long HDMI cable respectively. The converter is active, but not powered externally.
3. HDMI to VGA converter connects to a Monitor each via a VGA cable.

The problem I'm facing here is, the monitor with the 6m long cable always goes no signal after a few seconds of switching on the android tv box. The screen will show the startup logo of the tv box for about 10 seconds then it goes no signal, while the other monitor shows normally. The android box only outputs 720p video and audio.

Is there any solution to this problem? on the condition that HDMI cables cannot be changed and the converters cannot be made to have external power.

Comment: You have a hdmi to vga splitter connected to a pc and Android device connected to a monitor. You mean a splitter not a switch?

Comment: No I do not have a hdmi to vga splitter connected to a pc.

I am using just the android device. and from this device, a hdmi splitter is connected. the splitter is 1 in 4 out hdmi to hdmi splitter.